# Is Speed Baking 3 achievement possible without cheating?

Tags: achievements, cookie-clicker

I'm trying to get the achievement for Speed Baking 3. It's tough. Is it even possible without cheating?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. I never cheated and got most achievements. It is key to start clicking a lot! And focus on the upgrades that increase clicking power. Don't just blindly buy any upgrades but plan your upgrade path so you don't waste cookies on upgrades that won't increase your income significantly.

See also this [information page](https://cookieclicker.fandom.com/wiki/Speed_baking_III) for a strategy about getting the achievement.

Comment: Most upgrades are better than most buildings that early in the game. For instance Reinforced Index Finger doubles your clicks and costs less than 4 cursors. I would have thought aiming for upgrades would be more useful than buildings. Any other tips?

Comment: From you're advice it seems like you haven't got this achievement. You can only get the Speed baking achievements on your first game or through the Born Again reincarnation in which you don't get benefits of milk or heavenly upgrades or season switching.

Comment: @Coomie ah sorry! I forgot. I did get the achievement, but that was 4 years ago. I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but I REALLY wouldn't recommend it. You'd have to be getting consecutive golden cookies with frenzies and click frenzies every time, and overall it's super RNG-based, took over 120 tries for me to get. (Sidenote-I also used an auto clicker). Ofc, you also have to invest well, but honestly I just bought whatever was cheapest and it worked out.

Comment: Using an auto clicker is cheating.

Comment: I wouldn't really call it cheating, it's more or less the same as just clicking really fast but you don't get carpal tunnel.